# How do I access exfat files on Ubuntu 20.04 with missing permissions

Tags: 20.04, permissions, mount, automount, exfat

When I manually mount or have caja automount an external usb hdd I can only see limited files/directories.

```
$ sudo mount -t exfat -o rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2 /dev/sdd1 /media/user/exfathdd
$ ls -l exfathdd
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E01': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E02': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E03': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E04': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E05': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E06': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E07': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E08': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E09': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E10': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E11': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E12': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E13': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E14': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E15': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1.E16': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exfathdd/62922A1_E01_report': No such file or directory
total 65536
drwxr-xr-x 2 wallyz wallyz 33554432 May  5 07:37 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E01
d????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1_E01_report
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E02
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E03
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E04
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E05
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E06
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E07
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E08
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E09
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E10
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E11
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E12
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E13
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E14
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E15
-????????? ? ?      ?             ?            ?  62922A1.E16
drwxr-xr-x 2 wallyz wallyz 33554432 May  5 07:35 'System Volume Information'
```

Where ever there are valid permissions shown I can access that file or directory but nothing can be accessed where ever ???????? is shown.

Access is fine from a Windows 10 system (as expected).

I tried 'sudo chmod a+rw *' but that cannot access the file to make the change!

Using 'echo *' has no issue and prints all file/directory names.

kernel is 5.13 so exfat-fuse shouldn't be needed and installing it breaks exfat mounting completely.

I assume I have a mount option missing.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I suggest running `chkdsk` on the drive in Windows. This looks like corruption or some kind of file system error.

Comment: @Nmath I can definitely access the files without issue from Windows. However after running chkdsk on the media it indeed had issues.  After chkdsk fixed the issues I can now access the files from Ubuntu.  Thanks!!!  Add your suggestion as an answer add I will mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors suggest that there could be a corrupted file system.

Because exFAT is a file system developed by Microsoft, it's generally better to use Windows' utilities to fix file system problems with exFAT.

Boot into Windows and use the `chkdsk` utility on this volume.  This will check the file system for errors and fix common problems.